# Whitespace character regular expression behavior in different browsers

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-7

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukiano/FBQ9w/), I have the following javascript statement:

```
document.write("one two three".split(/\S+/).length);​
```

It prints **4** in Firefox and Chrome, also in IE9. But in IE7 it prints **2**.

I'm looking for a way to split by whitespaces with consistent behavior between browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lowercase s, like this

```
document.write("one two three".split(/\s+/).length);
```

This way the result will be 3, which is the answer that you want.

Comment: Haha I saw that copy/paste mess up!

Comment: @ianpgall I changed in the Fiddle and forgot to copy that code again :)

Comment: No problem, I know you edited, I just thought it was funny as I read your first sentence, saw the capital "S", then saw the edit come up...all in the matter of seconds!

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I see that capital S is the negated version.